# How do I display Rows in a table where all values but the first one for a column is null

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am trying to pull rows from a table where there are more than one version for an ID that has at least one person for the ID that is not null but the versions that come after it are null.

So, if i had a statement like:

```
select ID, version, person from table1
```

the output would be:

```
ID  Version  Person
--  -------  ------
 1        1  Tom 
 1        2  null 
 1        3  null   
 2        1  null
 2        2  null   
 2        3  null
 3        1  Mary
 3        2  Mary
 4        1  Joseph
 4        2  null   
 4        3  Samantha
```

The version number can have an infinite value and is not limited.

I want to pull ID 1 version 2/3, and ID 4 Version 2.

So in the case of ID 2 where the person is null for all three rows I don't need these rows.  And in the case of ID 3 version 1 and 2 I don't need these rows because there is never a null value.

This is a very simple version of the table I am working with but the "real" table is a lot more complicated with a bunch of joins already in it.

The desired output would be:

```
ID     Version     Person
--     -------     ------
1        2           null
1        3           null    
4        2           null
```

The result set that I am looking for is where in a previous version for the same ID there was a person listed but is now null.

Comment: Its not entirely clear to me what exactly you're looking for as the result.  Could you write out the desired output from your example in table format?

Comment: its for work...I am just a lowly minion, I don't do the why I just do :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeking all rows where the `person is not null` and that `id` has null rows, and the not null person `version` is less than the null `version` for the same person id:

**Edited predicate based on comment**

```
with sample_data as
  (select 1 id, 1 version, 'Tom' person from dual union all
  select 1, 2, null from dual union all
  select 1, 3, null from dual union all
  select 2, 1, null from dual union all
  select 2, 2, null from dual union all
  select 2, 3, null from dual union all
  select 3, 1, 'Mary' from dual union all
  select 3, 2, 'Mary' from dual union all
  select 4, 1, 'Joseph' from dual union all
  select 4, 2, null from dual union all
  select 4, 3, 'Samantha' from dual)
select *
from sample_data sd
where person is null
and exists
  (select 1 from sample_data 
    where id = sd.id 
      and person is not null 
      and version < sd.version);

/* Old predicate
    and id in
      (select id from sample_data where person is not null);
*/
```

Comment: Close, but I am seeking all rows where person is null but in a previous version there was a person there.

Comment: If you run the statement above, you will get exactly the same as the  result set you posted in your question.

Comment: The only problem is that the table i provided was just something simple I made up.  The actual result data has over 100 ids and can have versions that can go for an infinite amount.  The data I receive also constantly changes so unfortunately I can't list out each ID, version, and person every time I need the query to run.  Thanks though, I wish it was this simple :(

Comment: @user2498741 If you need the Name to be defined in a previous version, (IE ID= 2, Version = 4, Person = Sam should not match) then please add that to your question.

Comment: @user2498741 So I changed the predicate from an `IN` to an `EXISTS` and included the version level check.

Comment: @Wolf Thanks I had to change some stuff around but the general idea from your query helped me solve the problem :D

Answer (score 3):

I think this query translates pretty nicely into what you asked for?

*List all the rows (R) where the person is null, but only if a previous row (P) with a non-null name exists.*

```
select * 
  from table1 r
 where r.person is null
   and exists(
         select 'x'
           from table1 p
          where p.id = r.id
            and p.version < r.version
            and p.person is not null
       );
```

Comment: what is the "select 'x'"??

Comment: @user2498741: It's nothing. It's just an idiom. I'm not interested in retreiving any data, I just want to test if there is a row that satisfied the predicates. Other variations are `select 1` or `select null`. Doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the below should work.

```
select ID, listagg(version, ', ') within group (order by version) as versions
from table1 t1
where 0 < (select count(*) from table1 t1A where t1A.ID = t1.ID and t1A.version is not null)
and 0 < (select count(*) from table1 t1B where t1B.ID = t1.ID and t1B.version is null)
and person is null
group by ID
```

Comment: I edited based on your most recent update to the question. Does this work?

Comment: I am about to leave work but I will check it out tomorrow.  Plus I have never seen listagg before so I want to do some research as to what it is so i can better understand how to implement the query you provided into my "main" query.  Thanks :D

Comment: listagg is just a way to combine values from a field where a group by was done, I included it here to get a comma-separated list of the versions for each group

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
select id, version, person
from
 (
   select id, version, person,
      lag(person, 1) ignore nulls
      over (partition by id
            order by version) as x
   from table1
 ) dt
where person is null 
  and x is not null
```